# Can't manipulate lines by dragging in JavaFX scene builder

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am using Windows and I can't change the points of lines by dragging them in the editor with the mouse. The problem seems to only be happening on the Windows version of Scene Builder 2.0. On a MacBook this is not a problem.

What gives? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating lines by dragging and dropping the endpoint doesn't work for me on either Windows or OS X.

Editing and shapes by dragging points is largely unsupported in SceneBuilder 2.0.

There is an existing tweak request in the JavaFX issue tracker:

- [Content panel should provide editing gestures for CubicCurve, QuadCurve, Polygon...](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-6598)

I commented on the request to note that even basic lines cannot be manipulated.

Quote from the developer (Eric Le Ponner) for the feature request:

> Yes, there are no gestures for editing Shape currently. The only way to edit
>   shapes is by changing properties in the Inspector panel, which I agree
>   is far from being user friendly.
>
> On the other hand, vector editing is a vast subject (some software are
>   specialized into that :). And Scene Builder will never become a vector
>   drawing tool. So the key point is to define what would be interesting
>   in the context of a tool like Scene Builder. Any specific request is
>   welcome.

Requests can be filed against the design tool project at:

- https://javafx-jira.kenai.com